# Ocultar un botón cuando usuario no esté logeado

Tags: javascript, php

¿Cómo podría hacer que si el usuario no está logeado, no le aparezca el botón de salir?

En el CSS tengo una clase `.exit-click` con el atributo `display:block;`. He intentado que al momento de que el cliente cierre su sesión, se oculte el botón con:

```
document.getElementsByClassName(".exit-click").style.display="none";
```

Sin embargo no tuve resultado.

Estoy usando php, js, css, jquery.

Comment: Ocultalo de lado del servidor (php). Puedes evaluar con una variable de sesión si está logueado, no muestre el botón; de lo contrario, que lo muestre.

Answer (score 0):

**JQuery**

Debes utilizar un disparador, por ejemplo el boton `logout`

```
$(".exit-click").hide();
```

**Definición y uso**

El método `hide()` oculta los elementos seleccionados.

**Sugerencia:** Esto es similar a la propiedad CSS `display:none.`

**Nota** : los elementos ocultos no se mostrarán en absoluto (ya no afectan el diseño de la página).

**Sugerencia:** para mostrar elementos ocultos, consulte el método `show()`

codigo completo

```
$("btnlogout").click(function(){
  $(".exit-click").hide();
});
```